# Reloading a Core Data UITableView after iCloud update

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am currently using iCloud to sync Core Data between devices. The sync of data between devices is working but the call to reload the data of the `UITableView` containing the data is faulty. This is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(pushListLearn:)
                                             name:@"receivedLocalNotification"
                                           object:nil];

- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}
```

If I leave the device updating alone, the `UITableView` updates successfully with the new data appearing. However, if another device **deletes** an object on another device **while the main device is open and scrolling** (reloading individual cell data), my app crashes with the following:

> [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Here is my `UITableView` configuration if you require it:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to add to the following method is to reload the `UITableView` directly after the fetch:

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```